# Understanding Method Mechanism in C#?

Tags: c#, methods

Why is `i` not changed when I pass it to a method? The value of `i` after the method call is `0`, but the method still returns `101`.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Before static method running i={0}", i);
        int c=   SampleClass.ExampleMethod( i);
        Console.WriteLine("i={0} - Static method return c={1}",i,c);
    }
}

class SampleClass
{
    public static int ExampleMethod(int i)
    { 
    i= 101;
    Console.WriteLine("Inside static method i={0}",i);
    return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is... I isn't really passed to your class function.  A copy of I is sent.  You have to explicitly tell C# to send the actual value in memory instead of a copy.  You do this using the "ref" keyword.  In this example... I changes...

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0; 
        int c = SampleClass.ExampleMethod(ref i); Console.WriteLine("i={0} - c={1}", i, c);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

class SampleClass
{
    public static int ExampleMethod( ref int i)
    {
        i = 101;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In C#, value types (`int`s, `double`s, etc., are passed by value, **not** reference. )

In order to modify the value of `i`, you must use the [`ref`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int c=   SampleClass.ExampleMethod(ref i);
        Console.WriteLine("i={0} - c={1}",i,c);
    }
 }

class SampleClass
{
    public static int ExampleMethod(ref int i)
    {
        i = 101;
        return i;
    }
}
```

Usually, it is best practice not to use `ref`, and instead return a single value. Although in this case it is not clear on your intentions, so go with what works.

Comment: OK but I think I am missing someting , I cant understand comprehensively.Does  Method parameters i only live in method, is it true or false?

Comment: Using the ref keyword, the actual pointer to the variable `i` is passed, while normally it would pass a "copy"

Comment: To answer your question, once you enter the method a local copy of your ORIGINAL `i` is created. In your case, you are calling this local (method) copy `i` also. But yes, the methods local `i` only exists inside the method, and it's value is returned at the end, without changing the original.

Comment: This answer is wrong. *All* types are passed by value if you don't add the ref keyword. That's the point of the ref keyword.

Comment: You mean the MSDN link you pasted that says: "***Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types.*** The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference." :)

Comment: I see your point, with a reference type using ref, you can change what it points to. Without ref, you can only modify its variables/properties. Writing from a phone so not able to type very well.